# how to write a Nginx server block based on port in host header?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I would like to respond with different HTTP status code based on "port" in HTTP host header. The Host header looks like this :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.200.18:80
Connection: close
```

I wrote a server block which works fine as it compare hostname is host header  "10.0.200.18" with "server_name". Is there anyway I can write a condition based on host "port" ?

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  10.0.200.244;
    if ($host != $server_name) {
            return 500 $scheme://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The variable is [`$server_port`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_port), but if your `server` block does not `listen` on that port, then it will never match anyway. What you're trying to do doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MichaelHampton $server_port doesn't seem to be working. I am looking for port in host header, not the server port that server listening on. Actually I have the set up     ( Client---(80)Proxy---(8080) Nginx). So I am looking for the Host header that client is sending "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.200.18:80" , in this case 80 and server_port is 8080. Both are not same. I can write server section based on "$host" but which checks only the hostname in host header. I want to check "host_port in host header as well " . Thanks

Comment: Do you know that the proxy sends the Host: header with the port like the client sends it?

Comment: OK, now I think I understand what you want, but you still didn't explain why you want it, so it still doesn't make much sense. This isn't something you should ever realistically want in any scenario I can imagine (and quite possibly in any scenario the nginx maintainers can imagine).

Comment: @TeroKilkanen no. Proxy sometimes modifies the host_port in host_header. But host_name remains same.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Now lets say proxy is blackbox , and it modifies the host_port in host_header . I want to make sure that my application responds if the host_port in host_header matches server_listener port.